# How to pass list to jasper in grails using JasperService

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

Here is my Domain class

```
class User {
    String admin
    String name
    String phoneNumber
    String email
    String questionSet
}
```

Here is my view.gsp for Jasper report

```
<g:jasperReport controller="profile" action="jasperdata" format="PDF"
</g:jasperReport>
```

And here is my controller

```
def jasperService
def jasperdata(){
    List listDetails = []
    Map mapDetails =[:]
    Map result = [:]
    def number=User.executeQuery('select phoneNumber from User')
    mapDetails.put('phnno', number)
    listDetails.add(mapDetails)
    println listDetails
    result.data = []
    result.data << [phnno:listDetails]      
    JasperReportDef rep = jasperService.buildReportDefinition(params,request.locale,result)
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = jasperService.generateReport(rep)
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 'transaction' + ".pdf")
    response.contentType = "application/pdf"
    response.outputStream << stream.toByteArray()
}
```

I can send a single data item to Jasper But i want to send list of data from controller.

Answer (score 1):

domain is ok but in your controller you can try:

```
def jasperService
       def jasperdata = { User -> user
            List<User> listPhoneNumber = User.list() as Object[]
            JasperReportDef rep = jasperService.buildReportDefinition(params,request.locale,[data:listPhoneNumber])
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = jasperService.generateReport(rep)

            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 'transaction' + ".pdf")
            response.contentType = "application/pdf"
            response.outputStream << stream.toByteArray()
            response.outputStream.flush()
        }
```

View you can try too:

```
<g:jasperReport action="profile" controller="jasperdata" format="PDF" jasper="listPhone">
</g:jasperReport>
```

And a listPhone.jrxml, just for a simple test.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="relatorio" language="groovy" 

pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5f768b17-5eec-48ad-bfb8-2c500ea4eedb">
        <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
        <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
        <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
        <style name="Title" fontName="Arial" fontSize="26" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
        <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
        <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
        <style name="Detail" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12"/>
        <field name="phoneNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>

        <background>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <title>
            <band height="26" splitType="Stretch">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="3e5957c3-d694-428b-bcd9-173b2b40d517"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[LIST OF PHONE NUMBER]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </title>
        <pageHeader>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </pageHeader>
        <columnHeader>
            <band height="36" splitType="Stretch">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="11" width="555" height="20" uuid="467b7009-00d7-48e7-81c4-7037fcddc5ea"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Verdana" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[PHONES]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </columnHeader>
        <detail>
            <band height="29" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20" uuid="03b9a4c5-59da-4df7-9435-835eda1e83aa"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{phoneNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </detail>
        <columnFooter>
            <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
        </columnFooter>
        <pageFooter>
            <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="455" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="b53eb0ee-b2b4-4a82-871b-bd622b308572"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </pageFooter>
        <summary>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </summary>
    </jasperReport>
```

Hope it helps.